# Internal direct sum of infinitely many subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, direct-sum

I understand what the (external) direct product of an infinite number of vector spaces. I understand the internal direct sum of a finite number of vector spaces. I think I understand what an external direct sum of vector spaces is.

My question is,

Does it make sense to talk about an internal direct sum of infinitely many subspaces of a vector space? If so, how is this defined?

Comment: [Take a look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_vector_space).

Comment: @lzralbu What about [internal direct product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651553/what-is-internal-direct-sum-or-internal-direct-product-in-dummit-foote) please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. If $V$ is any vector space and $(W_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of subspaces of $V$, we write $$V =\bigoplus_{i\in I}W_i$$if the following conditions hold:

(i) for every $v\in V$ there are $i_1,\ldots,i_k\in I$ ($k$ depends on $v$) and $w_{i_1}\in W_{i_1}$, ..., $w_{i_k}\in W_{i_k}$ such that $$v=w_{i_1}+\cdots + w_{i_k}.$$This is written as $V=\sum_{i\in I}W_i$.

(ii) for every $j\in I$, we have $W_j\cap \sum_{i\neq j}W_i = \{0\}$.

Condition (ii) ensures that the decomposition of $v$ in (i) is unique. For example, if $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $V$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$, then $$V=\bigoplus_{i\in I}\mathbb{K}e_i,$$where each $\mathbb{K}e_i$ is the line spanned by $e_i$.

Comment: I have an issue with "$V = \sum_{i \in I} W_i$". Any subset of $V$ satisfies condition (i), so $\sum_{i \in I} W_i$ is not well-defined. Consequently, $\sum_{i \not = j} W_i$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Yeah, I read again and understood what you meant. But since $\sum_iW_i$ is the subspace generated by the $W_i$, we always have $\sum_i W_i \subseteq V$. Condition (i) is precisely the other inclusion $V \subseteq \sum_i W_i$. Now, if $U$ is any subset of $V$, then $U \subseteq \sum_i W_i$, but the reverse inclusion need not hold. I won't argue if you insist that my statement of (i) could have been written perhaps a bit more clearly, but it uses that $V$ is the entire space. How would you improve it?

Comment: (i) isn't the issue. It's your use of the word "this". I would say "The vector space containing each $W_i$ and satisfying (i) is denoted $\sum_i W_i$" or something like that.

Comment: @IvoTerek What about [internal direct product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651553/what-is-internal-direct-sum-or-internal-direct-product-in-dummit-foote) please?

Answer (score 2):

Let me add a more categorical description to Ivo Terek's answer. Given a family of subspaces $\{W_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $V$, we always have a canonical map from the "external" direct sum
$$ \bigoplus_{i \in I} W_i \to V,$$
given by the universal property of direct sum: a map out of the direct sum is a collection of maps out of the summands. We say that $V$ is the internal direct sum of the family $\{W_i\}_{i \in I}$ if this canonical map is an isomorphism. Spelling out the conditions for this map to be an isomorphism give exactly the conditions in Ivo Terek's answer.

Comment: why is external in quotes?

Comment: Joshua Mundinger What about [internal direct product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651553/what-is-internal-direct-sum-or-internal-direct-product-in-dummit-foote) please?