# What is internal direct sum or internal direct product in Dummit and Foote?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum, direct-product, graded-rings

I refer to Dummit and Foote Chapter 10.3 specifically pages [351](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azd2b.png),[353](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSWyt.png),[354](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dXX5.png),[356](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKIa7.png) and [357](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEf6h.png).

1. Does Exercise 10.3.21 on pages [357](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEf6h.png) (By the way, there's some errata here. Condition (iii) should be $i_1,...,i_k$) define a notion of **internal direct sum** (of unital $R$-submodules of a unital $R$-module over a unital, but not necessarily commutative, ring $R$)?

- I think this is an internal direct sum for an infinite or a finite index set that generalises the notion of internal direct sum for a finite index set given in page [354](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dXX5.png).

2. Do we have a notion of '**internal direct product**'?

- For the finite case, I believe this is the '$N_1 + ... + N_k$' part of Proposition 10.5 in page [353](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSWyt.png).
- For the finite or infinite case, I believe this is the 'the (unital $R$-)submodule of $M$ generated by (the union of) all the $N_i$'s' part of Condition (i) of Exercise 10.3.21 because '$N_1 + ... + N_k$' in Proposition 10.5 is actually equal to (see page [351](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azd2b.png)) the (unital $R$-) 'submodule of $M$ generated by (the union of) all the $N_i$'s' such that Condition (i) generalises the '(1)' in Proposition 10.5.
- **Therefore**: I think of internal direct product of $N_i$'s of $M$ as $\sum_{i \in I} N_i = R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$, which like external direct product and external direct sum, is always defined. And then I think of internal direct sum as not always defined but, whenever defined, as equal to internal direct product.
- Possibly relevant: 'Semidirect product'. This wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups#Generalization_to_sums_over_infinite_sets

Context: I'm trying to understand the direct sum parts of graded rings and graded ideals in later in [Chapter 11.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enfj1.png). I'm hoping these can be internal instead of just external. I ask more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723913/properties-of-graded-rings-and-their-not-necessarily-graded-ideals-part-2).

---

Edit 1: Thank you for the upvotes or views. I feel like all the hours I spent trying to understand this seemingly minor thing was really worth it.

Edit 2: For (not necessarily Abelian) groups: [Internal direct product/sum in groups: Is join and independent equivalent to unique expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288073/internal-direct-product-sum-in-groups-is-join-and-independent-equivalent-to-uni)

Comment: What is $ R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @rschwieb It's in [p.351](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azd2b.png)

Comment: For an infinite index set $I$?  That's clearly not always going to generate the product. Suppose $I$ is infinite but $R$ is finite. Then the submodule you're describing is countable, but the product is uncountable.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh right yeah I forgot about the $I$. I weirdly thought you asking only about the $R\{\cdot\}$. Here, $I$ is any nonempty index set.

Comment: Also in my comment above I should have specified $I$ countably infinite.

Comment: @rschwieb As for your edit...wait so what is 'the (unital $R$-)submodule of $M$ generated by (the union of) all the $N_i$'s' if not $R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$?

Comment: @rschwieb Wait, do you mean 'submodule of $M$ generated by (the union of) all the $N_i$'s' could be countable while $R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$ is uncountable for countably infinite $I$? I'm confused. I thought '$R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$' **is** the internal direct product and then my understanding is that under certain conditions '$R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$' is going to be called internal direct sum and denoted as '$\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i$'

Comment: @rschwieb, how should I understand internal direct sum in [Chapter 11.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enfj1.png) if not that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i = \sum_{i \in I} N_i = R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$ (with $N_i$'s and $R$ satisfying the relevant conditions) ?

Answer (score 5):

Let me know if this answers your question. Let's let $R$ denote a unital ring. There are two similar but slightly distinct notions of internal and external direct sum, which I think is at the core of the question here. First and foremost, let $M$ denote an $R-$module, and let $N_1,\ldots, N_k$ denote submodules of $M$. In particular, as sets $N_i\subseteq M$ for each $i$. We say that $M$ is an **internal direct sum** of the $N_i$, denoted by
$$ M=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k N_i$$
if every element of $M$ can be written uniquely as a sum of elements in the $N_i$. That is, for every $m\in M$, there exists a unique tuple $(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$ such that $m=\sum n_i$. It is equivalent to require that $N_1+\cdots+N_k=M$ and $N_i\cap N_j=\varnothing$ for $i\ne j$.

There is a slightly different notion of **(external) direct sum** where we take a collection of $R-$modules $N_1',\ldots, N_r'$ and we say that $M$ is an (external) direct sum of the $N_i'$ if there exists an isomorphism $\phi:M\to \bigoplus_{i=1}^k N_i'$. I.e.
$$ \boxed{M\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^k N_i'}$$
There is a bit of a distinction here, because we need to define this operation $\oplus$ for modules that do not both belong to a bigger module a priori. This is defined by the familiar rule
$$ A\oplus B=\{(a,b): a\in A,b\in B\}$$
subject to the obvious $R-$module structure. So, being an external direct sum can be translated into the terminology of the internal direct sum as follows: $M$ is the external direct sum of $\{N_i'\}_{i=1}^k$
$$ \phi:M\xrightarrow{\sim} \bigoplus_{i=1}^k N_i'$$
if and only if there exist $N_i\subseteq M$ with $\phi(N_i)=N_i'$ for $i=1,\ldots, k$ and in fact $M$ is the internal direct sum of the $N_i$. That is, the $N_i'$ define $N_i=\phi^{-1}(N_i')$ so that $M$ is an internal direct sum of the $N_i$.

**example:** We should interpret what $\mathbb{R}^2=\Bbb{R}\oplus \Bbb{R}$ means. It means that there is a pair of subspaces $L_1,L_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, each isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ so that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is their direct sum. In particular we can take $L_1$ to be the $x-$axis and $L_2$ to be the $y-$axis. These choices are far from unique.

Anyway, as you might know: this carries over almost verbatim to the case of an infinite indexing set, except that for $I$ a general indexing set, $\bigoplus_{i\in I}N_i$ consists of the finite sums of elements in the various $N_i$. So, you can re-define these notions in that case as an exercise.

If you are really interested in direct products, i.e. $M=\prod_{i=1}^k N_i$, then you should notice that for $R-$modules, finite products are isomorphic to finite coproducts (direct sums). I.e.
$$ \prod_{i=1}^k N_i\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^k N_i$$
and so the discussion carries over verbatim. In the case of infinite products, we get distinct notions:
$$ \prod_{i\in I} N_i\not\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i$$
but you can still define the analogous notion of "internal" direct product using the same strategy.

Comment: It sounds like you answer my questions, but I think I'd have to read a little more into your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Alekos Robotis, do you agree with rschwieb please?

Comment: Agree with him on what topic?

Comment: well, do you agree with rschwieb's answer...?

Comment: I believe so. Certainly $1.$ is true, and I think the issue he points out in $2.$ is quite valid also. You will not be able to describe the infinite product using sums. A general element of $\prod N_i$ is an infinite sequence $(n_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $n_i\in N_i$ for each $i$. (I have upvoted it, anyway.)

Comment: Even though $N_i$'s are modules that are submodules of the same module $M$, when you talk about '$\prod N_i$' as a set of infinite sequences, this is an external product i.e. it disregards $M$? If so, then this is not what I am talking about. I'm talking about $N_1 + N_2 + ...$ not $N_1 \times N_2 \times ...$

Comment: Alekos Robotis, how should I understand internal direct sum in [Chapter 11.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enfj1.png) if not that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i = \sum_{i \in I} N_i = R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$ (with $N_i$'s and $R$ satisfying the relevant conditions) ?

Comment: Regarding your first question: this set of infinite sequences can also be turned into an internal notion. If $M$ contains all of the $N_i$, and $M\cong \prod_{i\in I} N_i$ then you might say that this is an internal direct sum (though one might have to be a bit careful here). Regarding the second question: depending how you define the symbol $R\{\bigcup_{i\in I} N_i\}$, I think that it is okay to say $\bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i=R\{\bigcup_{i\in I} N_i\}$. This construction gives you the direct sum, but not the direct product.

Comment: What's wrong with calling $R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$ (defined on [p.351](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azd2b.png)) as internal direct product and then calling this internal direct sum when the condition is satisfied?

Comment: Sorry, above I should have written $M\cong \prod_{i\in I} N_i$ as internal _direct product_ in the comment. I can't edit now. The issue is that in general direct sum and direct product are distinct.

Comment: For me, it's like internal direct sum and internal direct product are equal whenever they are defined. How do you define internal direct sum without it being equal to internal direct product? My view is that internal direct sum is what you call internal direct product when the condition is satisfied. I know external direct product is not necessarily isomorphic to external direct sum.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon The direct sum is a proper subset of the direct product for infinite index sets.  They are equal for finite index sets.  LIke I said, you can see this even from the standpoint of cardinality. For the field of two elements $F_2$, $|\oplus_\mathbb N F_2|=\aleph_0$ but $|\prod_\mathbb N F_2|> \aleph_0$.

Comment: Ok actually something I didn't really get, what does it mean when you talk of $\prod_{\mathbb N} F_2$ as an internal direct product? I know what it means as an external direct product. I view the internal direct product more as $\sum_{\mathbb N} F_2$ than $\prod_{\mathbb N} F_2$, where $\sum_{\mathbb N} F_2 = R \{\cdot\}$

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon For me, the adjectives "internal/external" don't belong in front of "product", except in this question, which is the first time i"ve entertained the idea to any depth.  In my last comment, I meant to compare "the product" with "the (external) sum"

Comment: Alekos Robotis, cc @rschwieb, Ok actually something I didn't really get, what does it mean when you talk of $\prod_{\mathbb N} F_2$ as an internal direct product? I know what it means as an external direct product. I view the internal direct product more as $\sum_{\mathbb N} F_2$ than $\prod_{\mathbb N} F_2$, where $\sum_{\mathbb N} F_2 = R \{\cdot\}$

Comment: @rschwieb Why not? There's $N_1 + ... + N_n$ as internal direct product and then $N_1 \times ... \times N_n$ as external direct product...I guess?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I use the $\oplus$ to mean "external sum" when the modules involved aren't submodules of a common module, and I also use it to mean "internal sum" when they are.  Category theorists like to write it as $\coprod$.  The full cartesian product $\prod$ with $\times$ i use only for the product.

Comment: This is really helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it does.
2. Well, the factors of a product are clearly submodules of the product, but the issue is that since addition is finitary, it can never be additively generate the whole product.

I have never seen the notion of an "internal direct product" entertained, but there could be something to be said about characterizing it.

Proposition 10.5 proves that for finite sets, the direct sum and direct product coincide.

If it is helpful, here is [my version of explaining how internal/external sums are related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691956/29335). Maybe it will help you see why there is a finitary constraint on sums, and not on products.

Comment: Thanks. Re the second question, I don't get it. So am I right? Or what?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I don’t know if any characterization of a product in terms of sub modules.  The cardinals try reason I gave shows why your idea won’t suffice.

Comment: wait so what is 'the (unital $R$-)submodule of $M$ generated by (the union of) all the $N_i$'s' if not $R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$?

Comment: rschwieb, how should I understand internal direct sum in [Chapter 11.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enfj1.png) if not that $\bigoplus_{i \in I} N_i = \sum_{i \in I} N_i = R\{\bigcup_{i \in I} N_i\}$ (with $N_i$'s and $R$ satisfying the relevant conditions) ?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon That's a valid description of the internal direct *sum* but a sum like this will never be able to generate the *product* out of the same generators ( the union you chose) and addition.

Comment: rschwieb, can i just have a definition of internal direct product such that internal direct product isn't necessarily isomorphic to external direct product?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon if the $N_i$ are finite and $R$ is finite and $I$ is countable, $R(\bigcup N_i)$ is countable. But $\prod N_i$ is uncountable, yes.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I think the whole point of the description is to be isomorphic to the external product.   There *might* be a characterization, but it isn't in terms of just the module operations.