# About module decomposition in Atiyah-Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, notation, modules, direct-sum

I am reading p. 20 of *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and Macdonald. Given a module decomposition

$$
A=\mathfrak{a}_1\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathfrak{a}_n
$$ of ring $A$ as direct sum of ideals $\mathfrak{a}_i$ What does module decomposition mean in this line?

1. Internal direct sum
2. External direct sum
3. $\mathfrak{a}_i \cap \mathfrak{a}_j=0$ for $i\neq j$

Comment: As far as I know, the third thing is not a thing that is used anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This means internal direct sum. By definition, $\mathfrak{a}_i\cap \mathfrak{a}_j=0$ for $i\ne j$ and $\mathfrak{a}_1+\cdots+\mathfrak{a}_n=A$.

Comment: He didn't define internal direct sum but he uses it , and it confuses me for hours.

Comment: Well there isn't _really_ a big difference between internal and external direct sum. I wrote an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651553/what-is-internal-direct-sum-or-internal-direct-product-in-dummit-foote/3723951#3723951 which explains in part what I mean, if you're interested. That is, it shows how the two notions are closely related.

Comment: @LordShadow The contextual cue is that the things you are summing are subsets of the thing they sum to.  On the other hand if you just take two random $\mathbb F$ vector spaces $V,W$, $V\oplus W$ could not initially be called "internal' because $V,W$ are not common subsets of a set at the beginning. However, they *are* (isomorphic to) common subsets of their external direct product, and you *can* say that the external product of two things is itself an internal product of two subsets, each of which is a copy of $V,W$.  That's basically what's described at the link Alekos gave.