# How to determine whether $\mathbb Z_{p^m}$ is decomposable into (normal) subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-sum

**QUESTION**:

> Consider the group $G = \mathbb Z_{p^m}$, where $p$ is prime and the
> integer $m \ge 2$. How can I determine whether or not $G$ is an internal [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) of its (normal) subgroups?

---

At least I assume the definition is [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288073/internal-direct-product-sum-in-groups-is-join-and-independent-equivalent-to-uni) to the following: there exists positive integer $k$ s.t. there exist proper, nontrivial, normal subgroups $N_1, \dotsc, N_k$ of $G$ where

1. $G$ is the join of $N_i$'s (i.e. $G$ is equal to the subgroup generated by the union of $N_i$'s) and
2. the subgroups satisfy the independence property that for each $j=1,\dotsc,k$, we have that $N_j \cap \bigvee_{i \ne j} N_i = \{0_G\}$, the singleton containing the identity $0_G$ of $G$.

- **Idea 1**: I think [Keith Conrad (Eg 2.3)](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/finite-abelian.pdf) ('A cyclic group of prime-power order is indecomposable.') says precisely there does not exist a $k$, I believe. However, we're not yet allowed to use Cauchy's theorem (which Keith Conrad does)! See below for [Keith Conrad (Eg 2.3)](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/finite-abelian.pdf)

  > **Example 2.3.** A cyclic group of prime-power order is indecomposable. Let $A$ be cyclic of order $p^k$ where $k \geq 1$. If $A = B \oplus C$ where $B$ and $C$ are nontrivial subgroups of $A$ then $B$ and $C$ have $p$-power order greater than $1$ and thus $B$ and $C$ each contain a subgroup of order $p$ by <strike>Cauchy's theorem</strike>. That implies $A$ has more than one subgroup of order $p$, but in a cyclic group there is at most one subgroup per size. Thus $A$ is indecomposable.

---

**Update:**

- **Idea 1 (expanded)**: Actually, I don't have to use the full Cauchy's theorem (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) or [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cauchypf.pdf). in each link, there's a proof wherein the proof has like a case for Abelian).

1. There's a version of Cauchy's theorem for Abelian groups.
2. Better yet, I should recall that Cauchy's theorem is merely a partial converse to Lagrange's theorem. What's another partial converse to Lagrange's theorem? converse of Lagrange's theorem for finite cyclic groups! see '[proof of the converse of Lagrange’s theorem for finite cyclic groups](https://planetmath.org/proofoftheconverseoflagrangestheoremforfinitecyclicgroups)'.

How we continue in Keith Conrad Example 2.3 is like we have that both $B$ and $C$ have respective subgroups of order $p$ $H_B$ and $H_C$. We have in turn that $H_B$ and $H_C$ are subgroups of order $p$ of the original $G$. We have that this violates either

1. (assuming they are distinct subgroups indeed) converse of Lagrange's theorem for finite cyclic groups again! Well at least the stronger version that says there is exactly 1 subgroup. Here it's just at least 1 subgroup.
2. (assuming they are equal) well $B$ and $C$ intersect trivially so if $H_B=H_C$, then $H_B=H_C=\{0_G\}$. But the trivial subgroup doesn't have order $p$ unless the group is trivial, which is of course not the case.

And then in my case here...I just choose we can think of $N_i$'s as any decomposition of $m$ by sums like $m=a+b$ or $m=a_1+a_2+...+a_k$ and the extend by the argument above.

---

Please help for the non-(prime power) case: [Whether or not a (cyclic and thus Abelian) group $\mathbb Z_{n \ne p^m}$ (not prime power) is decomposable into (normal) subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4289088/)

---

References.

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) [What is internal direct sum or internal direct product in Dummit and Foote?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651553/what-is-internal-direct-sum-or-internal-direct-product-in-dummit-and-foote)

Comment: All you've done in one is show that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is indecomposable. You have not actually determined what you were asked to determine. This isn't a "choose $p$ and $n$" problem. This is a "figure out what the anwer is for all possible values of $p$ and $n$" problem.

Comment: "I must determine whether these groups $G$ [are decomposable/indecomposable]."  The groups in question being groups of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$. You only determined this for the groups of the form $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. So, this is not a "choose $p$ and $n$" problem. This is "here is a family of groups. Determine precisely which elements of this family are indecomposable." Isn't that clear from the syntax of the sentence?

Comment: I've said it before, and I'll say it one last time: the fact that you do not see whether that sentence settles things indicates that you *do not have the necessary knowledge to be trying to do these problems.* You are quite simply too unprepared and too confused. You need to go back and learn the **basics**, because you clearly do not have them down yet. It's a waste of everyone's time: it's a waste of yours because you spend enormous amount of effort twisting and turning with problems you don't understand, and waste of ours because you are not equipped to understand the answers.

Comment: What is the question here really? Is it "Determine whether $G$ is decomposable"?

Comment: @user yes. $ \ $

Comment: May I ask where this question is from? An exercise from Dummit and Foote or somewhere else?

Comment: @user from homework. you're asking because the wording is weird and doesn't sound like the exact wording in homework? look i'm just rephrasing the proof of keith conrad for my case

Comment: If you are taking a course in abstract algebra, it would be helpful for the readers to know what book you are using for the problems.

Comment: @user ah yeah good idea. i removed the other ideas just now. thanks! as for the book we don't really a direct book exactly just lecture notes and textbook references but many exercises in lecture notes i wasn't able to find in our textbooks.

Comment: You have a link to "internal direct product/internal direct sum". Is it supposed to be the definition you use in the course?

Comment: @user no the definition is the join + independent thing i gave. i was just pointing out that 1.5 years ago i had asked a related question

Comment: Okay. Do you read that definition from the lecture? Or a book? Do you have a solid reference for that?

Comment: @user lecture notes provide the definition. it's not even called direct sum in the homework even though it is in the lecture. it's the join + independent and then explain whether or not there exist $k$ given $(p,m)$

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon: Do you have a link to the lecture notes? That would be a helpful thing to add to the post. Reads do not share the same course as you do. It is difficult to step in the middle of a course unless you provide the complete notes.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the unnecessary rant in the comments, I think now the question is quite simple to answer in simple terms.

I am using multiplicative notation because it is how one usually starts when studying finite groups, so the group $\mathbb Z_n$ is the group whose elements are $\{1, a, a^2, \ldots , a^{n-1}\}$ You only need to use the following "theorem":

If $n$ is a natural number, the group $G = \mathbb Z_n$ has one subgroup for each divisor $d$ of $n$, call it $G_d$, and it can be described explicitly as follows:
$$
G_d = \{g \in G \mid g^d = 1\}
$$
This can be proven only using Lagrange's theorem and a little bit of manipulations, but it is really easy and you should try to prove it by yourself.

Now, concerning the groups $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$. Note that $p^n$ has exactly $n+1$ divisors: $\{1, p, \ldots , p^n\}$. If $g \in G_{p^k}$, $g \in G_{p^{k+1}}$ (this is by the description of these groups, and therefore we have an ascending chain
$$
\{1\} = G_1 \subset G_p \subset \ldots \subset G_{p^{n-1}} \subset G_{p^n} = G 
$$
This proves that the group is idecomposable: If you wanted to write G as the product of some $N_k$, then no $N_k$ can be $G$ (condition (2) would not be guaranteed), but then all of them are contained in $G_{p^{n-1}}$ and therefore, so is their join, and so condition (1) is not guaranteed.

Comment: I left your spelling of "idecomposable", because I was not sure what you meant.  Else, I did minor spelling/typo edits.